# how to use Autolt decrypt function in C++?

Tags: c++, encryption

I use this Autolt function do encrypt my string.(example 2)
https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/libfunctions/_Crypt_EncryptData.htm
it work well for decrypt and encrypt in Autolt.
But,I want to encrypt in Autolt and decrypt that in C++.
I try this code,but it didn't work.

```
    string Decrypt_string(char* Key, string HEX_Message, int size)
{
    static const char* const lut = "0123456789ABCDEF";
    int i = 0;
    char* Res;
    AES_KEY dec_key;
    string auxString, output, newString;

    for (i = 0; i < size; i += 2)
    {
        string byte = HEX_Message.substr(i, 2);
        char chr = (char)(int)strtol(byte.c_str(), NULL, 16);
        auxString.push_back(chr);
    }

    const char* Msg = auxString.c_str();
    Res = (char*)malloc(size);

    AES_set_decrypt_key((unsigned char*)Key, 128, &dec_key);

    for (i = 0; i <= size; i += 16)
    {
        AES_ecb_encrypt((unsigned char*)Msg + i, (unsigned char*)Res + i, &dec_key, AES_DECRYPT);
    }

    output.reserve(2 * size);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    {
        const unsigned char c = Res[i];
        output.push_back(lut[c >> 4]);
        output.push_back(lut[c & 15]);
    }

    int len = output.length();
    cout << output << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i += 2)
    {
        string byte = output.substr(i, 2);
        char chr = (char)(int)strtol(byte.c_str(), NULL, 16);
        newString.push_back(chr);
    }

    free(Res);

    return newString;
}
```

how to do that correctly?

Comment: What is the function doing that you don't want it to do, or not doing that you do want it to do?

Comment: I want to do _Crypt_EncryptData($sData, $sPassword, $CALG_AES_128) in Autolt

Comment: and do Crypt_DecryptData($sData, $sPassword, $CALG_AES_128) in c++,but i didnt find proper function to call